# Setup npm on node js builded sources

Tags: node.js, npm, build

So how to setup npm?
I created node_modules folder in Release folder and copied deps/npm folder there, after that I copied npm.cmd to Release. I can use npm, but I don't think It's true way.

Comment: You should include what operating system you're running. Node and npm setup differs somewhat depending on your OS.

Comment: I am running Windows 10.